# In Ruby, can I pass a variable number of lambdas into a method?

Tags: ruby, variables, lambda, arguments

I have the following code:

```
update_using(&add_tabs_before_every_description_line, &add_tabs_before_every_photo_description_line, &add_links_to_photo_descriptions)
```

where the three arguments are lambda expressions declared as follows:

```
add_tabs_before_every_description_line = lambda do |mutable_viewable_gallery|
  mutable_viewable_gallery.description = add_tabs_before_every_line(mutable_viewable_gallery.description, 2)
  return mutable_viewable_gallery
end
```

It doesn't work in that I cannot pass a variable number of lambdas to update_using which is declared as follows:

```
def update_using(*args)
```

The error I'm getting is exactly about passing more than one lambda. It expects exactly one and then a closing bracket, not a comma. As soon as I remove the ampersands, the syntax error goes away, but then update_using it doesn't see it as lambdas.

> generate_gallery.rb:50: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
>   ..._before_every_description_line, &add_tabs_before_every_photo...
>   ...

I would like to be able to pass a variable number of lambdas to update_using. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `&` operator, you pass your lambda (or other proc, or object that could be converted to proc) to the method as block. Now, you can't pass any arguments after block param (so you also cannot pass more than one block to method). I guess you should pass your lambdas as 'regular' arguments, without `&`:

```
update_using(add_tabs_before_every_description_line, add_tabs_before_every_photo_description_line, add_links_to_photo_descriptions)
```